# Show elements of array one by one - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a button on which I want to display each element of my array for a few seconds. This is my html code:

```
<button class="btn" id="random">Start</button>
```

I have made an array with jQuery that I want to use to change the buttons text:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#random").on("click", loop);
});

var array = ["el1","el2","el3"];

function loop() {
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        $("#random").html(array[i]);
    }
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length) + 1;
    $("#random").html(array[random]);
}
```

The `for` loop is supposed to do what I want but I can't find a way to delay the speed, it always just shows the last line of code. When I try `setTimeout` or something it just looks like it skips the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is to use [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/):

```js
var array = ["el1","el2","el3", "Start"];

function loop(){
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    (function(i) {
      $("#random").delay(1000).queue(function () {
        $(this).html(array[i]);
        $(this).dequeue();
      });
    })(i);
  }
}


$(function () {
  $("#random").on("click", loop);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn" id="random">Start</button>
```

Comment: i was looking for something with a loop in it so thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)** and **[`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)**

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $("#random").on("click", loop);
  }
);

var array = ["el1", "el2", "el3"];
var int;

function loop() {
  var i = 0; // variable for array index
  int && clearInterval(int); // clear any previous interval
  int = setInterval(function() { //store interval reference for clearing
    if (i == array.length) clearInterval(int); // clear interval if reached the last index
    $("#random").text(i == array.length ? 'Start' : array[i++]); // update text with array element atlast set back to button text
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" id="random">Start</button>
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you need to implement it using **[`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)** loop and **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)** then do something like this

```js
var array = ["el1", "el2", "el3", "Start"];

function loop() {
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#random").html(array[i]);
      }, i * 1000);
    })(i);
  }
}


$(function() {
  $("#random").on("click", loop);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn" id="random">Start</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly

Comment: @4eyes : glad to help  :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a for loop will not help you. It runs with the max speed it can. And delaying it would do no good in js (you would just freeze the browser). Instead, you can just make a function that will execute itself with a delay. Kinda recursion, but not entirely. Below would make the trick.

https://jsfiddle.net/7dryshay/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#random").on("click", function (event) {
    // texts to cycle
    var arr = ["el1","el2","el3"];

    // get the button elem (we need it in this scope)
    var $el = $(event.target);

    // iteation function (kinda recursive)
    var iter = function () {

      // no more stuff to display
      if (arr.length === 0) return;

      // get top of the array and set it on button
      $el.text(arr.shift());

      // proceed to next iteration
      setTimeout(iter, 500);
    }

    // start first iteration
    iter();
  });
});
```